# zend studio + xampp server file transfer

Tags: ide, dreamweaver, aptana, zend-studio

i been using aptana and dreamweaver for some long time, but now i wanted to use zend studio, because of there latest release and it says it can help on debugging while coding on javascript/php.

Now the thing is, i keep my project in different location and testing project in different location, just for safety and some wired thing dont happen, which sometimes empty the code for no reason. anyway in other two application i can easily make remote connection and transfer the file using the arrow button or by keyboard CTRL+ALT+U . it will upload and i can just refresh the browser to check it. on zend, i dont see any remote connections and i did change the server connection, but im not sure how i can easily transfer files, like i do in other IDE. can anyone help me on this for creating a remote connection and setting up the keywords, so i can continue to do what i use to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found File Synchronization plugin for eclipse, that worked out pretty well too, its just it will auto upload, rather then i will press ctrl+alt+u, which i like more better then auto. oh well, something better then nothing.